# Is it possible to choose on what part of a set of data a Vulkan compute shader starts on?

Tags: vulkan, compute-shader

If I had a group of 1000 vectors for example, would I be able to explicitly choose to start work on the first 1 - 100, then 101 - 200, 201 - 300... etc?

Comment: The order in which the shader invocations is outside of your control. You could use some atomic operations to get some ordering done. Or you can maunally synchronize stuff, but only inside workgroups, not between different workgroups. If you want some guaranteed ordering between workgroups, you need to do several dispatch calls with proper synchronization inbetween.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a shader do whatever you want. If you have some array of data, you can compute the array index however you like. Being that it is a compute shader, you don't have user-defined inputs, so you have to use a push constant or similar uniform data to instruct the shader as to how to get its data.

If you have Vulkan 1.1+ available, and don't need to use indirect dispatches, you can use `vkCmdDispatchBase`, which takes base indices for the work groups. Otherwise, the work group/item indices will always start from 0 for all dispatch operations.

Comment: What about `vkCmdDispatchBase()`?

Comment: @user369070: I didn't know about that function; it's newer. But there is no indirect version of it, so it is of limited usability.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, that has helped me a lot :D.